# Como fazer para que uma regex capture uma grande variação de um termo? (CASA, Casa)

Tags: java, regex

É o seguinte: dado que tenha um termo que desejo capturar, por exemplo, "CASA", como fazer uma regex para que se capture *muitas* variações dessa palavra, exemplo:

> Casa, CASa, CAsa, casa, CaSA, CasA...

Sei que há

> (Casa|CASa|CAsa|casa|CaSA|CasA)

mas vejam que para isso é necessário que eu escreva todas as variações existentes da palavra, que seria 16 para "CASA". A depender da palavra, isso se tornaria uma tarefa hercúlea. Os regex possuem um mecanismo que facilite nossas vidas quanto a isso?

Comment: Não poderia ser assim (?i)(casa) ? com o (?i) significando Case-Insensitive, assim daria match em todas as combinações possível de "casa "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
/(casa)/ig
```

Explicação:

- (palavra): Grupo de captura dos caracteres literalmente
- /i: modificador para insensitivo
- /g: modificador para global

Para o Java, como comentou @AronLinhares, deve ser:

```
(?i)(casa)
```

**Regexr:** http://regexr.com/3ev1q

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a flag de `CASE_INSENSITIVE`. Veja [esse exemplo funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/Mq4JMX):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("casa", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        System.out.println(p.matcher("Casa").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("CaSa").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("CAsA").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("casa").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("CaSA").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("Sopa").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("Carro").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("Verde").matches());
    }
}
```